# How to access share folder from windows to AWS ubuntu ec2 instance?

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, network-share

I am creating internal CRM portal, this tool is used for running scripts and get the data from HANA cloud.

We have 40 scripts and 2 result template excel files stored in share folder - '\10.xx.xx.xxx\abcd\MR Reporting\SQL_Execution\Apollo\Prospective'.

**I used React(FE) and Node JS (BE) - As soon as script execution form is submitted from FE, BE API will read the script from share folder, and reads the result template and create the new result file same as template with result data and stores back to share folder again.
**

Basically this works fine if I run it in my local, because for my company mail ID I have this share folder access.

**I deployed my Node JS server in AWS ec2 ubuntu instance, from there I want to have the same functionality Running. Is it possible to do, Any other implementation suggestions are appreciated.
**

Is there any way i can give share folder access to public IP address

Note *: This Share folder access is not one time. It will be dynamic in the script execution api code flow.

I referred this
[How to share from windows to ubuntu](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-access-windows-shared-folder-from-ubuntu#:%7E:text=Mount%20the%20Windows%20shared%20folder,username%3DUSERNAME%2Cpassword%3DPASSWORD)

But it didn't work.

Comment: Need help here, anyone know how to resolve this.